# Summing the results of a loop in VBA, Excel

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I'm trying to sum the results of a loop. So far the code takes values from WsIn by row, runs them through a model and gives results in WsOut. The code takes the values in row 1 and gives results based on these and goes back and does it for row 2 and so on. The results are overwritten by the new results as the code loops. But I want it to add the results given by row 1 to the results given by row 2 added to row 3, etc. The results are ranges C5:C33 and D5:D33 in WsOut. I think the code for this would be something like the loop I put at the bottom but I'm not sure how to make this. Any ideas on what I should do?

```
Sub TEST1()

Dim WsIn As Worksheet               ' Input
Dim WsT As Worksheet                ' Taken
Dim WsOut As Worksheet              ' Output
Dim WsMod As Worksheet              ' Model
Dim Arr As Variant
Dim Rl As Long
Dim R As Long
Dim Rout As Long                    ' WsOut row
Dim Cmod As Long                    ' WsMod column

Dim XXX As Integer
Dim YYY As Integer
Dim WWW As Integer



Set WsT = Sheets("Inputs Taken")
Set WsIn = Sheets("Input Values")
Set WsOut = Sheets("Output")
Set WsMod = Sheets("Model")





Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Rl = WsIn.Cells(WsIn.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
For R = 2 To Rl
    'Pasting Input Values into Inputs Taken
    With WsIn
        Arr = .Range(.Cells(R, 1), .Cells(R, 4)).Value
        WsT.Cells(5, "D").Resize(UBound(Arr, 2), UBound(Arr)) _
                         .Value = Application.Transpose(Arr)
        Arr = .Range(.Cells(R, 5), .Cells(R, 6)).Value
        WsT.Cells(11, "C").Resize(UBound(Arr), UBound(Arr, 2)).Value = Arr
        Arr = .Range(.Cells(R, 7), .Cells(R, 8)).Value
        WsT.Cells(16, "C").Resize(UBound(Arr), UBound(Arr, 2)).Value = Arr
        Arr = .Range(.Cells(R, 9), .Cells(R, 14)).Value
        WsT.Cells(9, "G").Resize(UBound(Arr, 2), UBound(Arr)) _
                         .Value = Application.Transpose(Arr)
        Arr = .Range(.Cells(R, 15), .Cells(R, 16)).Value
        WsT.Cells(20, "C").Resize(UBound(Arr, 2), UBound(Arr)) _
                         .Value = Application.Transpose(Arr)
        Arr = .Range(.Cells(R, 17), .Cells(R, 18)).Value
        WsT.Cells(20, "D").Resize(UBound(Arr, 2), UBound(Arr)) _
                         .Value = Application.Transpose(Arr)


    End With

    'Setting Opening PUP to 100% and refreshing
    WsT.Cells(5, "G").Value = 1
    Application.CalculateFull

    'Calculating No RPs
    With WsOut
        Cmod = 62                       ' BJ:BP
        For Rout = 7 To 13
                .Cells(Rout, "C").Value = SumProduct(Cmod, WsMod)
                Cmod = Cmod + 1
        Next Rout
        .Cells(14, 3).Value = Application.Sum(.Range("C11:C13"))

        Cmod = 71                       ' BS:CB
        For Rout = 17 To 26
            .Cells(Rout, "C").Value = SumProduct(Cmod, WsMod, True)
            Cmod = Cmod + 1
        Next Rout
        .Cells(5, 3).Value = WsMod.Cells(6, "BL").Value _
                           - WsMod.Cells(6, "BS").Value _
                           - WsMod.Cells(6, "BT").Value
        .Cells(15, 3).Value = Application.Sum(.Range("C5,C7:C10, C14"))
        .Cells(27, 3).Value = Application.Sum(.Range("C17:C26"))
        .Cells(29, 3).Value = Application.Sum(WsMod.Range("AN6:AN365"))
        .Cells(30, 3).Value = Application.Sum(WsMod.Range("AP6:AP365"))
        .Cells(31, 3).Value = WsOut.Cells(2, 3).Value
        .Cells(33, 3).Value = WsOut.Cells(15, 3) - Application.Sum(.Range("C29:C31, C27"))
    End With

    'Changing PUP rate
    WsT.Cells(5, "G").Value = 0
    Application.CalculateFull


    'Calculate with RP
    With WsOut
        Cmod = 62                       ' BJ:BP
        For Rout = 7 To 13
                .Cells(Rout, "D").Value = SumProduct(Cmod, WsMod)
                Cmod = Cmod + 1
        Next Rout
        .Cells(14, 4).Value = Application.Sum(.Range("D11:D13"))

        Cmod = 71                       ' BS:CB
        For Rout = 17 To 26
            .Cells(Rout, "D").Value = SumProduct(Cmod, WsMod, True)
            Cmod = Cmod + 1
        Next Rout
        .Cells(5, 4).Value = WsMod.Cells(6, "BL").Value _
                           - WsMod.Cells(6, "BS").Value _
                           - WsMod.Cells(6, "BT").Value
        .Cells(15, 4).Value = Application.Sum(.Range("D5,D7:D10, D14"))
        .Cells(27, 4).Value = Application.Sum(.Range("D17:D26"))
        .Cells(29, 4).Value = Application.Sum(WsMod.Range("AN6:AN365"))
        .Cells(30, 4).Value = Application.Sum(WsMod.Range("AP6:AP365"))
        .Cells(31, 4).Value = WsOut.Cells(2, 3).Value
        .Cells(33, 4).Value = WsOut.Cells(15, 4) - Application.Sum(.Range("D29:D31, D27"))
    End With

'Exit For
    Next R
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

        For XXX = 5 To 33
        For YYY = 6 To 7
         For WWW = 3 To 4
           WsOut.Cells(XXX, YYY).Value = WsOut.Cells(XXX, WWW).Value

    Next WWW
    Next YYY
    Next XXX


End Sub

Private Function SumProduct(ByVal Cmod As Long, _
                            WsMod As Worksheet, _
                            Optional ByVal Negative As Boolean) As Double
    Dim AuxRng As Range

    With WsMod
        Set AuxRng = .Range(.Cells(6, Cmod), .Cells(365, Cmod))
        SumProduct = Application.SumProduct( _
                    .Range("AD6:AD365"), _
                    .Range("AG6:AG365"), _
                     AuxRng)
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: Sometimes it is tough to read code without seeing context. Can you post sample of original results (after model), current results (after posted code), and desired results?

Comment: Declare a variable to store the result and add the value of the next result while looping, don't write the result but the value of that variable to your output cell - something like `var = var + ResultValueOfCurrentLoop` and `Cells(...).Value = var`

Comment: @Parfait The results after the model is run for row 1 are:
 1.15   1.15 
 0.05   673.82 

 0.03   5.24 
 20.62   20.62 
 12.37   12.37 
 - 23.92
 32.99   56.91 
 34.21   737.12 

 0.32   0.32 
 0.02   267.74 
 0.07   30.29 
 0.02   7.22 
 0.02   6.73 
 0.35   0.35 
 0.05   0.05 
 0.00   0.00 
 0.85   312.70 

 0.40   0.40 
 0.06   0.06 
 720.00   785.23

-687.10  -361.27
The 1st column is C and the 2nd is D. It will then loop and give another set of numbers the same as above using the next row in WsIn. I want it to sum this column C and D with the next loops results.

Comment: @Parfait the numbers didn't paste like I thought they would but they are just two columns of numbers.

Comment: Do not post data or code in comments. Instead, [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61274761/edit) your post with such content. Once done, delete these long comments. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Have an integer add to itself at the end of each loop. totNum = totNum + this rows count. At the end total sum will = totNum.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean by this. Why would I add an integer? What do you mean by this rows count?

Comment: Dim total as int
Right after you get your results of row 1  do total = row 1 results.
At the end of row 2 or whatever do total = total + row 2 and so on.